# vertical alignment - floated element in nav bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to vertically align two left and right floated elements in a nav bar. (Where the 'collapsed' nav bar has had the clearfix hack applied). The height of the navbar is determined by the left floated title (h2, 2em by default).  However the right floated element, a form with input and button,  doesn't sit centrally even when trying the transform approach to vertically centering items?
If I uncomment the transform vertical alignment approach it just sends form further up (not down and centred).

CodePen(https://codepen.io/yunti/pen/xdvpQK)

```
https://codepen.io/yunti/pen/xdvpQK
```

[image: unaligned nav]

```css
.header {
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.header-title {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-header {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*top: 50%;*/
  /*transform: translateY(-50%);*/
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

input,
button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header clearfix">
  <h1 class="header-title">Weather App</h1>
  <div class="form-header">
    <form class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="St. George, Utah" />
      <button class="btn">Get Weather</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox makes this really easy. Just add `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;` to the parent, and that will separate the elements in the parent and align them vertically.

```css
.header {
  background-color: darkorange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-title {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-header {
  padding-right: 10px;
}


.form-control {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;

  line-height: 1.42857143;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="header-title">Weather App</h1>
  <div class="form-header">
    <form class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="St. George, Utah" />
      <button class="btn">Get Weather</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to use flexbox, you can use `display: table` on the parent, `display: table-cell` on the children in combination with `vertical-align: middle`

```css
.header {
  background-color: darkorange;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.header-title {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-title, .form-header {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.form-header {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;

  line-height: 1.42857143;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="header-title">Weather App</h1>
  <div class="form-header">
    <form class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="St. George, Utah" />
      <button class="btn">Get Weather</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer (I should have mentioned need to support ie9 so can't do flexbox but thanks for the other answer).  Any ideas why the tranform approach doesn't work? (mentioned in other SO answers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control `For relatively positioned elements, the top or bottom property specifies the vertical offset from the normal position and the left or right property specifies the horizontal offset.`  When you're using a `%` in top/left/right/bottom, that is only for `fixed` or `absolute` or `sticky` position, since that % is relative to the parent. % on a relatively positioned element does nothing. It works if you use `50px` instead of `50%` instead.

Comment: but isn't the approach in the question a `relative` position? not a `fixed`, `absolute` or `sticky`?

Comment: Yes... *"% on a relatively positioned element does nothing. It works if you use 50px instead of 50% instead."* % refers to it's position from the parent, which only applies if you're using fixed, absolute, or sticky. `top` on a relatively positioned element doesn't care about the parent, so % values do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have different amounts of margin on your H1 element ("weather app" -- 22px) and your input/button (10px). Make your margin-top the same on all of these elements.